# PayPal is not working with iframe build in Ionic app

Tags: iframe, ionic-framework, paypal

PayPal  is not working with iframe build in Ionic app but it is working with 
InAppBrowser of ionic framework.
The Screen gets hang on Login of Paypal page within app.
Here {{src1}} is my website url which uses Paypal for payment purpose.

Can anyone suggest Paypal pages are not working with Iframe with ionic app?example code:

```
<ion-content >
   <ion-refresher on-refresh="refresh()"></ion-refresher>
    <iframe id="buyer" class= 'webPage' name= "eventsPage" src={{src1}} >
   </iframe> 
  </ion-content>
```

but working fine with below code.

```
 window.open("http://***********.com/dating/site/index_url/1/", "_self", "location=no")
```